# Firebase analytics, How to use UserProperty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to make an alertDialog:

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    askProxAtualiza();
 }

private void askProxAtualiza() {
        final String[] choices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tema_items);
        ContextThemeWrapper ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Theme_MediaRouter_Light);
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle(R.string.tema_dialog_title)
                .setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String tema = choices[which];
                        setUserFavoriteFood(tema);
                    }
                }).create();
        ad.show();
    }
}



private void setUserFavoriteFood(String next_up) {
    Log.d("XXXX", "Tema Favorito: " + next_up);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("next_up", next_up);
}
```

Then this happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0IEN.png

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I created a User Property on firebase page called next_up.
There was more one day that I did it.
The Results isn't showing on firebase page!!!:

[firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh78l.png)
Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

The values for "next_up" don't currently show in the auto-suggestions for next_up.  But when you go to the dashboard, select Add Filter->User Property->next_up and manually type a value, it should filter that report by users with that user property value.